# Should I remove HTTP to HTTPS redirects to fix performance problems reported by Google Pagespeed Insights?

Tags: redirects, https, performance, google-pagespeed

I have created a brand new website in which I publish various computing services I suggest to potential customers.

As far as I know, no other website on the World Wide Web links to that website and today in nearly mid 2021 when people create backinks, they normally just make them "example.com" (no `http://` or `https://` and no `www.`).

After testing the website in *Google Pagespeed Insights* I got only one error about slow loading times due to the specific reason of **four redirects**:

```
http://example.com | 630 ms
https://example.com | 480 ms
http://www.example.com | 630 ms
https://www.example.com | 480 ms
```

While I need the `www.` for a CDN to protect from possible DDoS attacks and using HTTPS as a web standard, principally I would never create non HTTPS backlinks to my website and don't worry from anyone on the planet doing that.

Given the current HTTPS culture and my site being currently backlinkless, should I remove HTTP to HTTPS redirects to fix performance problems reported by Google Pagespeed Insights?

### Update --- current `.htaccess` redirection directives

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When you say there are four redirects, is that a redirect chain where you hit the 1st, it redirects to the 2nd, then the the third, and finally to the fourth?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think that this is what happens ; I am not 100% sure myself...

Comment: If it matters, my hosting is shared (namecheap, Stellar Business plan).

Comment: If this is your redirect chain, then it is wrong to do it like that, as you switch from HTTPS to HTTP in the middle of things. You should stay in HTTPS all the time (and if possible collapse all redirects to just one). Other than that for anything new I think you shouldn't even bother to provide an HTTP version of the site, and just run out of port 443.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks, I wish I knew how to change my hosting partition to the scheme you have described; as this is a shared hosting environment I doubt that I have any control about this, but please allow me to update the question with an example of the current `.htaccess` redirect pattern.

Comment: The redirect directive you've posted is not consistent with the redirect "chain" that is being reported?! "should I remove HTTP to HTTPS redirects" - where are the HTTP to HTTPS redirect(s)? The directive you posted is not an HTTP to HTTPS redirect. "when people create backinks, they normally just make them "example.com" (no `http://` or `https://`" - That's impossible, for a site create a valid backlink, it _must_ have the protocol `http://` or `https://`. Don't confuse "backlinks" with a user typing the URL in a browser.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for the sharp comments; I don't have enough knowledge in Apache PCRE to comment about the directive so please share with us why you said it's inconsistent with the scheme Google presents. Today in nearly mid 2021 when people create backlinks these will automatically be HTTPS in most cases, won't these?

Comment: "it's inconsistent with the scheme Google presents." - because the directive you posted redirects to HTTP, but the first redirect hop reported by Google goes to HTTPS - so there must be "something else" doing this? "when people create backlinks these will automatically be HTTPS" - this is not "automatic", but it is in the interests of the linking site that the link is HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove HTTP to HTTPS redirects.

- Removing them won't fix performance problems.   Redirects only make it slower when users encounter them and most users should never see the redirects.  Once a user is on your site (`https://www.example.com/`), all the links should keep the `https` and `www`.  Users should never need the redirects once they are on the site.
- Some other sites may be linking to you with `http` or without `www`.   If you stop serving `http` those links would break.
- Type-in traffic typically hits `http` before getting redirected to `https`.  Users that type in "example.com" typically don't go straight to `https`.  A few browsers can now be configured to try `https` first, but it isn't the norm yet.
- If you are on shared hosting, you don't have the ability to turn off `http`.  Shared hosting web servers are configured for `http` and `https`, there is no site-specific way to turn off just one of them.  You  could configure your site to serve an error for `http`, but you wouldn't be able to stop the webserver from responding to `http` requests.

The best thing to do is remove redirect chains.  Your `.htaccess` rule currently has non-www traffic redirecting to `http` with the `www`.  You should change it to redirect to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is usually desirable to also redirect `http` to `https` in the same rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'd have to edit your site in place of `example.com` when using the rule.

Comment: Much thanks Stephen; I find this topic a bit confusing (why can't Apache PCRE be more simple and intuitive like Bash or modern JavaScript are?...)

Comment: I understand the combined rule as: `REDIRECT HTTP-NON_WWW, HTTP-WWW and HTTPS-NON_WWW to HTTPS-WWW` is that correct?

Comment: that is correct.  It redirects any combination except for the desired one directly to the desired one.

Comment: @RAMOS "why can't Apache PCRE be more simple and intuitive like Bash or modern JavaScript are?" - the regex engines used by Apache, Bash and JavaScript are all very similar. In fact, in the context of the directive above, they would be "the same". (Maybe you are not referring to regex, but to the syntax of the directives instead?)

Comment: @RAMOS For simple needs, Apache `RedirectX` directives are enough, you should look at them instead of `RewriteX`. I never understood why everyone uses `mod_rewrite` for needs completely fulfilled by `mod_redirect`.