# Https- and www-redirects accepted by Google Pagespeed Insights

Tags: htaccess, redirects, google-pagespeed

This question builds on this [stackexchange-thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/134465/should-i-remove-http-to-https-redirects-to-fix-performance-problems-reported-by/134537#134537)

The question of mentioned thread was how to write a proper http-to-https and nonwww-to-www redirect, that *Google Pagespeed Insights* would approve of. Stephen provided this clean answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However when implementing this code it runs into "The page isn’t redirecting properly" errors for all sub pages, e.g. example.com/xyz. The code seems to miss something to cover such scenarios.

With help of Google I changed Stephen's code to the below which seems to have resolved the issue with sub pages not redirecting (note I merely replaced "(.*)" by "^" ), however I'm no expert here and in all honesty don't really know what I'm doing. Moreover it seems this new code does cause some other (to me seemingly random) redirect issues.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**TLDR / Question**: how to fix above code snippet(s), so that the https and www redirects will work for all of example.com's URLs, including all of its sub pages?

*Note I had to create a separate thread because I'm lacking the reputation to respond to Stephen's answer directly..*

Comment: What else do you have in your .htaccess file?   When it isn't redirecting properly, where is it redirecting?   Can you run `curl --head https://example.com/` on the command line using https://curl.se/ for all four variants of your URL, as well as four more with sub pages and report the `Location:` header?

Comment: Hi @Stephen Ostermiller, thanks a lot for your thoughts. There is nothing else in the .htaccess file. If I implement your code again and use my browser's developer mode to see what "Network" information passes by when loading sub pages, it seems the problem is a 301 redirect loop. I see like twenty 301-lines after each other until the loading gets killed and the "The page isn’t redirecting properly" message appears. Please note that for my homepage this issue does not occur. I'm not familiar with curl.se. Can I run it on Windows too? And is it still helpful after my answers above?

Comment: "the problem is a 301 redirect loop" - but what is it redirecting from/to specifically? There is nothing "wrong" with the first rule. The resulting "error" is most certainly due to configuration differences (or application code) on your server. (There is no single "correct" HTTP to HTTPS redirect that will work on all servers.) However, your updated code does not really make sense (it redirects all sub pages to the homepage)... if that code avoids the "redirect" loop then it would seem to imply you perhaps have a conflicting redirect in your application code?

Comment: In addition to the `Location:` header mentioned above, it might be necessary to examine _all_ the HTTP response headers your server is sending back.

Comment: Aside... you should test with 302 (temporary) redirects (and/or with the browser inspector open and "caching disabled") - 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic. After implementing an erroneous redirect, you will likely see a cached response, even after changing your directives.

Comment: @MrWhite; thanks a lot, especially also for your comment about using 302 with testing. I wasn't doing that and I'm sure that caused part of the anomalies! After aligning with my hoster I'm now using this, which works nicely:

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Apparently my hoster was already redirecting https to http at its own behalf and as a result the htaccess code I added was causing the loop!

Comment: "now using this, which works nicely" - But that doesn't redirect to HTTPS (it explicitly redirects to "http")? "my hoster was already redirecting https to http" - ??? Don't you mean "to HTTPS"? (You should never redirect to "http" these days) It's possible your webhost (on a shared server) is using a caching proxy that renders the `HTTPS` Apache server variable useless (the host would then expose an alternative). However, the webhost would not normally _implement_ such a redirect (that is arguably being "too helpful").

Comment: Aside... short code snippets in comments should be surrounded in `backticks` to retain formating. Otherwise, as with the code you posted in the comment, certain characters can be omitted from display which makes the code invalid/incorrect at first glance.

Comment: Curl does run an Windows. You can download it from https://curl.se/windows/   It is a much more reliable way of testing redirects than browsers because it doesn't ever cache anything.

Comment: Is your host really redirect away from HTTPS?   If so, you should change that.  If you can't change it, you should find a new host.   Browsers now show errors for sites that don't support HTTPS.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all patience. With the code mentioned above (thanks for adding the backticks..) the result is that all visits end up on an HTTPS URL. My host does not redirect away from HTTPS, he by default redirects to HTTPS. The code mentioned is actually what they recommend using themselves. Am I understanding correctly that you would recommend replacing the http:// part by https:// to avoid an unnecessary redirect in the background?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace `http://` with `https://` in order to avoid an unnecessary _triple(?)_ redirect (when requesting HTTP and non-www). There is no "redirect in the _background_"  - these are all separate external redirects. (Since you do want to end up at HTTPS, why send users to plain old HTTP?) However, there may still be 2 redirects if the webhost has taken it upon themselves to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (on the same hostname I assume) in the server config. Check the network traffic in the browser when requesting the non-canonical HTTP + non-www - what do you see? What status codes?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response but that code unfortunately doesn't work for me. It results in a "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error for every page. (Of course I did replace example.com by my own domain..)

Comment: Have you spoken to tech support at your host? Maybe they have something in place at the server level that overrides what you put in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your comment. I contacted my host's support and the problem turned out to be caused by the fact that they were already redirecting https to http at their own behalf (hence the code I added caused the loop!). On a related note; how can I vote up comments like yours that have been helpful to me but exist in a comment thread like this one?

Comment: @Mike You can click on the up arrow in front of the comment - I'll upvote yours...